# jquery loop through multiple divs with Next/Prev Buttons

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using the following code to loop through divs which works perfectly

```js
$("#nextBtn").click(function() {
  var nextDiv = $(".step:visible").next(".step");
  if (nextDiv.length == 0) { // wrap around to beginning
    nextDiv = $(".step:first");
  }
  $(".step").hide();
  nextDiv.show();
});

$("#prevBtn").click(function() {
  var prevDiv = $(".step:visible").prev(".step");
  if (prevDiv.length == 0) { // wrap around to end
    prevDiv = $(".step:last");
  }
  $(".step").hide();
  prevDiv.show();
});
```

```css
.step {
  display: none;
}
div.step:first-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
  <div class="step">This is step 1</div>
  <div class="step">This is step 2</div>
  <div class="step">This is step 3</div>
  <div class="step">This is step 4</div>

  <button id="prevBtn">Prev</button>
  <button id="nextBtn">Next</button>
</div>
```

My problem is that I will have multiple sets of divs and buttons added dynamically and this breaks the code like below

```js
$("#nextBtn").click(function() {
  var nextDiv = $(".step:visible").next(".step");
  if (nextDiv.length == 0) { // wrap around to beginning
    nextDiv = $(".step:first");
  }
  $(".step").hide();
  nextDiv.show();
});

$("#prevBtn").click(function() {
  var prevDiv = $(".step:visible").prev(".step");
  if (prevDiv.length == 0) { // wrap around to end
    prevDiv = $(".step:last");
  }
  $(".step").hide();
  prevDiv.show();
});
```

```css
.step {
  display: none;
}
div.step:first-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
  <div class="step">This is step 1</div>
  <div class="step">This is step 2</div>
  <div class="step">This is step 3</div>
  <div class="step">This is step 4</div>

  <button id="prevBtn">Prev</button>
  <button id="nextBtn">Next</button>
</div>
 
 
 <div class="form">
  <div class="step">This is step 5</div>
  <div class="step">This is step 6</div>
  <div class="step">This is step 7</div>
  <div class="step">This is step 8</div>

  <button id="prevBtn">Prev</button>
  <button id="nextBtn">Next</button>
</div>
```

How can I make this work? as I cannot change the class of any element, nor will I know how many elements there will be?

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot add elements with the same ID into your page, in the snippet below I replace the IDs of the buttons with classes. Then, all you have to do is call the jquery parent() method to show/hide the element in the right form :)

I hope this may help :)

```js
$(".nextBtn").click(function() {
  var nextDiv = $(this).parent().find(".step:visible").next(".step");
  if (nextDiv.length == 0) { // wrap around to beginning
    nextDiv = $(this).parent().find(".step:first");
  }
  $(this).parent().find(".step").hide();
  nextDiv.show();
});

$(".prevBtn").click(function() {
  var prevDiv = $(this).parent().find(".step:visible").prev(".step");
  if (prevDiv.length == 0) { // wrap around to end
    prevDiv = $(this).parent().find(".step:last");
  }
  $(this).parent().find(".step").hide();
  prevDiv.show();
});
```

```css
.step {
  display: none;
}
div.step:first-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
  <div class="step">This is step 1</div>
  <div class="step">This is step 2</div>
  <div class="step">This is step 3</div>
  <div class="step">This is step 4</div>

  <button class="prevBtn">Prev</button>
  <button class="nextBtn">Next</button>
</div>
 
 
 <div class="form">
  <div class="step">This is step 5</div>
  <div class="step">This is step 6</div>
  <div class="step">This is step 7</div>
  <div class="step">This is step 8</div>

  <button class="prevBtn">Prev</button>
  <button class="nextBtn">Next</button>
</div>
```